# How do I use localStorage/Javascript to remember information (input values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I need some help with localstorage/JS. I want it so that when I enter names/number (values) and submit, it must automatically fill out these values when I re-visit the page (I dont wanna have to press the first letter to bring the suggestion up - it must always show the values last entered by default).

But I have ABSOLUTELY no idea what to look for. I've tried numerous "localstorage" codes but none seem to work for me.

```html
<div id="formular">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="formulartekst">
      <form>
        <h2 class="formskrift">Personal Information</h2>
        <input class="oplysninger" type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder="First Name">
        <br>
        <input class="oplysninger" type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder="Second Name">
        <br>
        <input class="oplysninger" type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder="Email or Number">
        <br>
        <textarea class="oplysninger" id="kommentar" name="Text1" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Order">
```

Comment: The [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is as simple as it gets - where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: Basically I have my input fields, and I wanna enter values. Then, when I click order, I want to be able to refresh the page and the values I typed must be there again by default.

Comment: I do not feel so but that is fine..OP wants it on submit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/g3ueqkzh/1/)

```
function submit()
{
   var text1 = document.getElementById( "text1" ).value;
   var text2 = document.getElementById( "text2" ).value;
   var text3 = document.getElementById( "text3" ).value;
   var text4 = document.getElementById( "kommentar" ).value;
   localStorage.setItem( "text1", text1 );
   localStorage.setItem( "text2", text2 );
   localStorage.setItem( "text3", text3 );
   localStorage.setItem( "text4", text4 );
   console.log( localStorage.getItem( "text1" ));
   return false;
}

window.onload = function()
{
   document.getElementById( "text1" ).value = localStorage.getItem( "text1" );
   document.getElementById( "text2" ).value = localStorage.getItem( "text2" );
   document.getElementById( "text3" ).value = localStorage.getItem( "text3" );
   document.getElementById( "kommentar" ).value= localStorage.getItem( "text4" );   
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. :)